# Ruby Rails - Cant locate routes.rb to add page to site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am currently working on a project where the majority if the site structure is already in place. I am trying to add a new section to it but am having difficulty getting links to work.

I replicated what another page had however in tutorials I am seeing reference to a routes.rb file which specifies how links work. The problem is i cannot locate the routes.rb file. Is there anything I am missing or is routes.rb specific to a certain version and I am using a different version. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: @Aetherus - I know it should be there but my config folder has the following files; apps.rb, boot.rb, deploy.rb, environments.yaml, settings.yaml and warble.rb as well as deploy and recipe folders but none of these seem to relate to the routes.rb file.

Comment: Are you sure it's a Rails application, not something else like `rack application` , `Sinatra application`, or `Goliath application`?

Comment: Apologies for my ignorance but we do use Sinatra. How can you tell what type of application it is and what are the differences or is this too broad of a sub-question?

Comment: Forgive my rudeness, for my English is not good. I saw apps.rb in the config dir, which is not a standard one for rails. Other ruby web applications mentioned above don't have standard file structures so I guess your application could be something other than Rails.

Comment: Not a problem (your English is pretty good). So could you tell me how i discover what type of application it is. I have taken this over from somebody who no longer works here so kinda on my own with this.

Comment: Since you're using Sinatra, you should have a file which contains something along the lines of [this](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Routes). It might be the `apps.rb` file. Try doing a search for `get`, `post`, `patch` in your project to find the correct file. Once you've got it, you can add a new `route` in there using the information which can be found on the page I've linked to.

Comment: @newmediafreak - You may be correct. Going to take a look now to make sure and if it is i'll get back to you.

Comment: Maybe the simplest way to distinguish application types is to go through the `Gemfile`, if there is one.

Comment: @Aetherus - In going through the gemfile what do i look for? Here are the contents of my gemfile;

Comment: gem 'padrino'
gem 'padrino-flash'
gem 'capistrano', '~> 3.0.1'
gem 'capistrano-rbenv'
gem 'capistrano-bundler'
gem 'dbi'
gem 'haml'
gem 'sass'
gem 'tilt'
gem 'rake'
gem 'rubyzip', '<1.0.0'
gem 'dberkom-sinatra-prawn'
gem 'sinatra-flash', require: 'sinatra/flash'
gem 'jruby-openssl'
gem 'jdbc-jtds', '~> 1.3.0.1'
gem 'dbd-jdbc', '~> 0.1.6'
gem 'bcrypt'
gem 'iso_country_codes'
gem 'prawn', '~> 1.2.1'
gem 'prawn-table', '~> 0.1.0'
gem 'jruby-jars', '1.7.15'
group :development do
  gem 'guard'
  gem 'guard-livereload'
end
group :production do
  gem 'mizuno'
end

Comment: You see `sinatra` in the Gemfile, so be it. Unfortunately sinatra applications don't have standard file structure. You'd better follow @newmediafreak 's suggestion.

Comment: Okay. So its a Sinatra application and i should use the system described in the link you provided then?

Comment: Search for `get`, `post`, ..., followed by a URL in all the files in your application. If you find something, those files will be your entrance to the code base.

Comment: @Aetherus - Thanks for the help. Much appreciated. You were correct. Also there was an issue with helpers.rb as it had a list of pages allowed when user was not logged in so i had to add a reference to the new page here also. To everyone else thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1):

I think your routes file was deleted. You can check `git status`. You will be find deleted file there. Rollback that change or create new file routes.rb in `config/` folder.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but somebody mentioned it may be a Sinatra, rack or goliath application. Think this is the issue as we use Sinatra.

Answer (score 0):

If the app is a standard Rails app, you should be able to find `routes.rb` in the app's `config/` folder.

Comment: I know it should be there but my config folder has the following files; apps.rb, boot.rb, deploy.rb, environments.yaml, settings.yaml and warble.rb as well as deploy and recipe folders but none of these seem to relate to the routes.rb file. As far as i know its a standard app.

Comment: It's possible that your app isn't using Rails, but Padrino – http://www.padrinorb.com

Answer (score 0):

How about just using your editor to do a file search and locate the file?

For Sublime Text, `cmd + p` for MAC will suffice.

Comment: I've already tried this but no luck. To repeat there is no routes.rb file in my application. Is there any other approach used other than routes.rb. Did wonder whether it was similar to the Asset Pipeline which i thought i was missing but which i was told is only used on certain versions.

Comment: @user3385136 Can you share your app if possible?